# Finding mutual elements between two higher-dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python. Here is my problem.

```
import numpy as np

def neighbors(indexset, i,j):
    temp = np.array([[i-1,j],[i+1,j],[i,j-1],[i,j+1]])
    for ele in temp:
        if ele in indexset: 
            print(ele)

indexset = np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]])
neighbors(indexset, 0,0)
```

When I run this I get values I don't understand

```
neighbors(indexset, 0,0)
[1 0]
[ 0 -1]
[0 1]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't this return only [0,1]?

Comment: Which are the two higher-dimensional numpy arrays in the sample?

Comment: the goal is to find shared elements of temp and indexset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting stange results because `ele in temp` is only appropriate if `ele` is a scalar. It uses the `numpy` function `__contains__`, which is equivalent to `(a==b).any()`. If you do this with python lists instead of numpy arrays, it works:

```
def neighbors(indexset, i,j):
    temp = [[i-1,j],[i+1,j],[i,j-1],[i,j+1]]
    for ele in temp:
        if ele in indexset: 
            print(ele)

indexset = [[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]]
neighbors(indexset, 0,0)
```

Will print `[0,1]` as expected. If `indexset` is always a numpy array, you can use `tolist`:

```
import numpy as np

def neighbors(indexset, i,j):
    temp = [[i-1,j],[i+1,j],[i,j-1],[i,j+1]]
    for ele in temp:
        if ele in indexset.tolist(): 
            print(ele)

indexset = np.array([[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]])
neighbors(indexset, 0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that the code works on lists. I think indexset needs to be a numpy array, though. 

The suggested revision with tolist doesn't quite work. 

I get 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element  is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). 

I guess I need a different approach than using 'in'

Comment: I get the same output as the list-only implementation. Did you use exactly what I wrote in the second part of my answer? Because `temp` needs to be a list as well, which it is in my function. Perhaps you left `temp` as a numpy array in your version of the `tolist` approach?

Comment: Yes, I can replicate your `ValueError` by making `temp` a numpy array in the `neighbours` function, and only using `tolist` on `indexset`. Just change `temp = np.array([[i-1,j],[i+1,j],[i,j-1],[i,j+1]])` to `temp = [[i-1,j],[i+1,j],[i,j-1],[i,j+1]]` in your version of `neighbours` that uses `tolist` and it'll work.

Comment: Oh I see! It does work. Thank you! I didn't realize temp was a list instead of a numpy array when I tried to implement your suggestion apart from this toy code.